# find the last created image file with remote or external link

Tags: php

HI guys i have some jpeg files with this format:

```
123-1.jpeg ,123-2.jpeg ,123-3.jpeg ,123-4.jpeg ....
```

This files located on my VPS and i need to find and show the lasted file by remote (my means external web link ).
i have problem how i can read files with such name format i tried this is not work:

```
$screnshot_url = "http://8.7.6.5/screenshots/123-*.jpeg ";


$filemtime = filemtime_remote($screnshot_url);
$files = $screnshot_url;
$files = array_combine($files, array_map($filemtime, $files));
arsort($files);
$img = key($files);


function filemtime_remote($uri)
{
$uri = parse_url($uri);
$handle = @fsockopen($uri['host'],80);
if(!$handle)
    return 0;

fputs($handle,"GET $uri[path] HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: $uri[host]\r\n\r\n");
$result = 0;
while(!feof($handle))
{
    $line = fgets($handle,1024);
    if(!trim($line))
        break;

    $col = strpos($line,':');
    if($col !== false)
    {
        $header = trim(substr($line,0,$col));
        $value = trim(substr($line,$col+1));
        if(strtolower($header) == 'last-modified')
        {
            $result = strtotime($value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
fclose($handle);
return $result;
}
```